# Drupal - How To Edit Home Page Source Code?

Tags: drupal

I'm new to Drupal so please bear with my beginner question.

i have this website that now i need to administer.
Unfortunately, it seems recently the website may have been hacked and hidden links been added into the home page (at the end, after footer).

i found it out when i view the page via **Right Click > View Page Source**

The hidden links is only added into the home page, not the other pages. However, i don't know how to open the home page's source code and edit to remove the links. i have go through every admin settings options available, i have tried google it as well, but none seems to be the answer.

ps. i have looked into the page.tpl.php on the server, nothing seems amiss there.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the help you have given!

I found the code inside ***theme.inc*** file. So once i remove this part of code, the website should be clean again, right? Please tell me if i need to do other things as this is my first time cleaning a hacked website (im really beginner at this)

In addition, i've performed a google search **"site:websitename.com"** and found that there are some unknown URL like ***"websitename.com/some-product-name"***. I've searched the nodes but found none related to it. And when clicked, the link redirect to another website altogether.

Really appreciate if you could guide me how to remove this as well.

Thank you!

Comment: The website might be clean but it will likely still be open to hacking. You will need to upgrade drupal core if the version was before 7.32, because there was a major sql injection issue that allowed to take control of the whole project and create admins accounts, alter/add php files. Best way to upgrade the core is to delete all core ditectories and replace them with new ones to remove any extra file.

Comment: @LaurentFauvel I see, was thinking of upgrading the drupal once i clean this up, or it should be upgrade first? Is there a list of the core directories to delete? Would be really helpful since idk which file is for what. Also,do you know how to remove the **_websitename.com/some-product-name_**? Saw some extra file and deleted it, but the URLs still exist.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look into the menus. But yep you should upgrade as soon as possible and reset the password of any user with back office rights if possible.

Comment: For the core upgrade, all files/directories should be deleted then replaced but the "sites" directory and its content should stay untouched. That is supposing there is no custom files on your  project. Check this link for more infos : https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290

Comment: @LaurentFauvel sorry, could you elaborate what do you mean by "taking a look into the menus"? Is that the **structure > menus > main menus** ? Meanwhile i'll try to do the upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: structure > menus, any menu under this one. Because it was one of the common approach of hackers with the sql injection attack, they will make an admin account then create menu links and usually use these menus links as a door to upload files. In your case it seems you have links still floating around pointing to another site, so I am guessing they are in the menus.

Comment: @LaurentFauvel nothing seems suspicious under the menus. I have update the Drupal and now when clicked it is directed to Page 404. However, the URL are still showing under the search result. Tried to remove them via **_Search Console » Google Index » Remove URLs_** but they shows again few days later.

Comment: So they are not on your pages but showing on google search results?
If they are still on your page and you searched the whole project for them and they are not hard written in a template for example. They could then be in paritcular node content or block (search under structure menu for block or search the content displaying them under content menu).
If they are not on your pages it is a problem with google robots not updating well your site (check your robots.txt is correct).
Also clear your Drupal cache (menu configuration > developpement > performances).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not in theme, it could be in a preprocess hook in pretty much any module, so search the whole project for a function having preprocess in it.
Another possibility are links injected by javascript so search all js files for the href of the malicious link (it costs nothing to actually search the whole project files for the target website in the href of these links).

You can do a global search loading the project sources in an IDE like eclipse/netbean... .

If the links are stocked in the database and not in the code, it will be tricky to find it, disable all modules one by one, switch to default theme, if nothing work replace current drupal core files with the ones from drupal.org in case they got corrupted (same version to avoid compatibility issues), so you can find which part of the site is causing this.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to open also html.tpl.php and (if exist) page--front.tpl.php. Also take a look to template.php
2. Update parent theme (if any) to latest version. Change theme and see if you still have issue. If issue resolved see 3. Or else see 4.
3. Download the whole theme to your local and search for some string of the bad code through all of the files strings
4. Update drupal and all its modules to latest versions

If nothing helps - provide the link to the website, so I could see if there something which could guide me to the goal

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could be the issue.

1. Check your code base for the malicious code. If you have access to a
   command line navigate to the document root and type **grep -Hirn
   "malicious-text-sample" ***
2. Search through your database for any content injections (they could
   have added blocks, boxes, etc. The easiest way to do this is to use
   a UI like PHPMyAdmin and search for a piece of the text.
3. Inspect element on the page and see if it is a script that is being
   inserted. You can usually do this by hitting f12 on the page in
   question.